# AngularJS password validation

Tags: angularjs

i'm learning from tutorial "Creating Apps With Angular, Node, and Token Authentication". And i've stuck. I found this code there:

html

```
<form name="register" class="form-signin" novalidate>
    <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Register</h1>
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email"
           class="form-control" placeholder="Email address"
           required autofocus>
    <p class="help-block"
       ng-show="register.email.$dirty && register.email.$invalid">
      Please enter a proper email.
    </p>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password"
           class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="password" name="password_confirm" ng-model="password_confirm"
           class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"
           validate-equals="password">
    <p class="help-block"
       ng-show="register.password_confirm.$invalid && register.password_confirm.$dirty">
      please match the passwords.
    </p>
    <button ng-disabled="register.$invalid" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

and js

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('validateEquals', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            function validateEqual(value) {
                var valid = (value === scope.$eval(attrs.validateEquals));
                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('equal', valid);
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            }
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(validateEqual);
            ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(validateEqual);
            scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            });

        }
    };
});
```

this directive according to the video should give me a proper two-way validation for `password` and `password_confirm` inputs, but it doesn't (on video it does work, i'm confused). It validates well, when i change value of `password_confirm` but when i change `password`, validation not work. Here is plunker [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4WZVBmE89BgbCgH2e0jS?p=preview). Question: What's wrong with that code? And how should i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, Thanks to JB Nizet :)

solution :

```
angular.module('learningAngularApp')
.directive('validateEquals', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$validators.validateEqual = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                var valid = (value === scope.$eval(attrs.validateEquals));
                return valid;
            }
            scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function () {
                ngModelCtrl.$validate();
            });

        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably is in this line:

```
ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
```

This line doesn't do anything. I gues sthat in a previous version of Angular, it retriggered the $parsers pipeline, and that in the current version, since it sets the view value to the same value that it already has, it has been optimized to not do anything.

This really looks like a hack to me. It should be replaced by something like

```
scope.$watch(attrs.validateEquals, function(firstPassword) {
    var valid = (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue === firstPassword);
    ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('equal', valid);
});
```

(not tested)

BTW, angular now has support for validators, which make things easier and don't force you to deal with parsers and formatters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController.

Comment: Thx a lot, validators are the right way, i will post my new working directive.